# Unzip archive in PCL project

Tags: android, windows-phone-8, xamarin, unzip, portable-class-library

I'm searching a solution to unzip a .zip archive in my PCL project (android, windows phone). I tried to use `System.IO.compression` Zip Archive but I have some problems with .dll (in particular for `System.IO.compression.FileSystem`).
Someone can help me? or suggest another solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly access the file system from a PCL.  Either open the stream in platform specific code and pass it down to the PCL, or use something like [PCL Storage](http://pclstorage.codeplex.com/).

If you aren't already doing so, you may need to reference the [Microsoft.Bcl.Compression](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Compression/3.9.84-beta) NuGet package to get the compression APIs in your PCL.